# This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 2021.1.1 or newer

Tags: android, unit-testing, mutation-testing

I am trying to use pitest plugin in a helloworld android studio project to do mutation testing. However after following the [instruction](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/pl.droidsonroids.pitest) it's giving following errors :

```
This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 2021.1.1 or newer.
```

I have `build.gradle` dependencies : `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'`
and gradlewrapper properties to : `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip`

Any help how to resolve this ?

Comment: Have you tried with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'`?

Comment: yes still same :/ also tried this `https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/info.solidsoft.pitest`